# SQL Server : Comparing Time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to compare time in my SQL query. However, when I run the query, I get zero result but I can see that in the table, there are records that should appear.

The query is as such:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Alarms 
WHERE StartDate <= '26/08/2015' 
  AND StartTime <= CONVERT(varchar(5), GETDATE(), 108)
```

The `StartDate` is stored in the database as `YYYY-MM-DD` and it seems to work fine when I query only with the date.

However, when I add the `StartTime` is when things don't work. `StartTime` stores the value in the 24 hour clock format.

What am not doing right?

Thanks

Comment: Post the datatypes that StartDate and StartTime are. If they are `VARCHAR` you should know that's a bad idea

Answer (score 2):

Use a correct datetime format:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Alarms
WHERE StartDate <= '2015-08-26' AND StartTime <= cast(GETDATE() as date)
```

Don't compare date/time values as strings.  The data types are built into the language.  Use them.

Comment: I tried this and realised that my table structure is not quite right. I cannot compare the date and time in seperate fields. I will try and create a new field of type datetime and see if I can compare using that.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask another question and include sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

I have not explicitly used this scenario but comparing dates can be a problem depending on how the fields are compared.

eg: `'28/07/2015'` is not less than your startdate as `28 > 26`.

You could try comparing dates reformatted into a `YYYYMMDD` format.

Cheers.

Comment: Reading your comments made me think of an aspect that I did not take into account. I don't think I can run this statement as such because if the startdate is less than today, then the time does not matter. The time only matters if the startdate is equal to today. I will try and create a new field with a type of datetime instead of seperating the two